# DB2 got error in execution of trigger during runtime

Tags: triggers, db2

I am using a global temporary table in my trigger, on execution time when the trigger is fired I got an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRG
  NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT ON ROSTS
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEWOBJ
 FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
 BEGIN

DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.EMP(INT) AS
(SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
WITH DATA ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
NOT LOGGED;   
END;

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: An error occurred in a triggered SQL statement in trigger "MYTRG".  Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-577", SQLSTATE "38002" and message tokens
```

Comment: Triggers can't reference DECLARED global temporary tables firstly. Secondly, avoid any DDLs in triggers. They are not suited for this. You should redesign your logic requiring such things on every single row inserts...

Comment: I think about mqt- tables to use in my trigger. How about mqtt tables here Instead of temporary table? The Table will be used often in triggers

Comment: To answer this question one should know much more additional information starting from what you try to do at all. If it's possible, say, to materialize the results once and use it for some time disregarding of the fact, that the base tables may be changed during this time. Is it possible? When / how do you want to / can refresh your MQT / CGTT? Other questions may arise as well...

Comment: I have a very complex checks in my trigger. I can guarantee that in that time no base tables will change but nevertheless I want to refresh the mqtt in each trigger perhaps manually , so is it possible to refresh mqtt tables in triggers?

Comment: This is not correct architecture. You should refresh your mqt **outside of triggers** first and use it (or base query which should be routed to this mqt if you are able to make it work) in your triggers if possible, or redesign your approach somehow else if not.

Comment: The view which I am using in trigger is a bit general. Is it possible to say in the trigger to use an Index for the view. `select * from myview where id = 2 `. by using the above condition an index Will be Used when i take the select of the view directy. But index is Not used in the above usage

Comment: As for "index is Not used in the above usage". How did you get it? Have you really got an explain plan for your whole `INSERT INTO` statement if your trigger is inlined (BEGIN ATOMIC ... END), or from catalog (with EXPLAIN_FROM_CATALOG routine, if you really know how to do it) if your trigger is compiled (BEGIN ... END as in your question), where you see that access to the base tables of your view is unanticipated? Note, that I don't use your "index for the view" term because views don't have indexes, and we may say, that some index on some base table of this view and not used instead...

Comment: The reason I asked the questions above is, that you can try to make the optimizer choose desired access method to some base table with optimization guidelines (inlined or in optimization profile), but the way you do it is different depending on what type of the trigger you chose - inlined or compiled. A guideline must be applied to the whole statement (INSERT) in case of the inlined trigger, and to the particular statement inside the compiled one. But these guideline application efforts usually start after examining the access plan only.

Comment: What you mean with this concretely
"A guideline must be applied to the whole statement (INSERT) in case of the inlined trigger, and to the particular statement inside the compiled one. "

Comment: `INSERT INTO ROSTS ... /*<OPTGUIDELINES><IXSCAN TABID="Qx"/></OPTGUIDELINES>*/` for the inlined trigger, `some_statement_referring_your_view /*<OPTGUIDELINES><IXSCAN TABID="Qy"/></OPTGUIDELINES>*/` inside the trigger body for the compiled one. The table references `Qn` here are from the access plans of the corresponding statements. These are inlined [optimization guideline](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=plans-optimization-profiles-guidelines) examples.

Comment: As I understand using of the optimization guidelines make sense when the optimizer not using the expected index. But this does not fit my question,I will explain more my context in a simplified example: I have a view like `CREATE VIEW MYVIEW (ID,NAME) AS SELECT ID,NAME FROM MYTABLE)`.In real the view is a bit much more complex. So nevertheless in my trigger I make a select on this view with a condition on id. But the select not consider the index,because the view has not a fixed condition on id (view is more generic) which enforces the opitimizer to use the index. I hope you got me now?

Comment: No, I don't understand you wording like "view has not fixed condition on id" and how it might be relatrd to the fact, that stanalone `select ... from myview where id = 2` uses index, but similar `select ... from myview where id = some_variable` in the trigger doesn't. If you don't use `where id = ...` in the trigger, then it's not clear what you want from the optimizer. So, it's time to update your question (or may be even create a new one, since this discussion has fallen into absolutely different direction) with the corresponding details.

Comment: It other words you shoul describe the trigger logic very schematically at least. Like how the data inserted into this table is related to the view contents.

Comment: I will create possibly a New question  More detailed. But what is exactly the difference between inlined and Compiled triggers?

Comment: Briefly. The statement fired an inlined trigger is optimised with the statements in the trigger as a single statement. It's not the case for a compiled trigger, which statements are not optimized with the triggered statement. These statements are rather executed separately as if they would be in some routine. Refer to the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement description in the documentation.